# Golang subslice with no numbers as a function arg

Tags: go, slice

I recently came across some code that looked like this

```
x := bytes.IndexByte(data[:], 1)
```

and upon removing the colon it seemed to work exactly the same, is there a purpose to the colon?

Comment: If data is a slice, then there is no reason to do this.

Comment: I believe it is, if it isn't a slice is there a reason to do this?

Comment: To convert an array to a slice, but then you would get a type error if you didn’t do it.

Comment: Sorry very new to Go, how would you get an array in Go that isn't a slice? I thought Go slices were arrays for the purpose of go

Comment: Arrays and slices are separate types. If you’re new to go I would start with the [Tour of Go](https://go.dev/tour) or at least the language spec.

Comment: Please work through the Tour of Go for such basic language fundamentals.

Answer (score 2):

In Go there is a difference between arrays and slices.  Every slice is tied to an array, either explicitly or implicitly, and the slice references a range of elements of the array.  For example,

```
x := [4]byte{0, 1, 2, 3}
```

defines an array of four bytes.  Since `bytes.IndexByte()` needs a slice (not an array) as its first argument, attempting to write `bytes.IndexByte(x, 1)` results in the error message `cannot use x (variable of type [4]byte) as type []byte in argument to bytes.IndexByte`.  To fix this, we need to define a slice which references the elements of `x`.  This can be done by writing `x[0:4]` or, shorter, `x[:]`.  Thus, the correct call of `bytes.IndexByte()` here would be

```
bytes.IndexByte(x[:], 1)
```

You say that in your case removing the `[:]` made no difference.  This indicates that `data` in your code already is a slice.  In this case, `data` and the "sub-slice" `data[:]` are identical and there would be no reason to write `data[:]` instead of `data`.

Some code to illustrate these points is at https://go.dev/play/p/yma1krRdNML .

Answer (score -3):

In Golang , x[:] refers to the storage of x. so x[:]==x only .If input value is already slice then it should not effect , otherwise it is required to convert array into a slice .